# Always show MB in PHP

Tags: php

Hello guys I am trying to understand how to do this, I found something similar here on the website but did not help, I believe it is simple for many.

Well I'm trying to always show in MB
This example below got right here, down there all right when you list to 1GB 999MB, 58MB list does not want to change I want to continue with MB GB (1000MB) like this forever. The same when KB does not list when list 999K (1MB)

```
function formatBytes($size, $precision = 2){
    $base = log($size) / log(1024);
    $suffixes = array('', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');   
    return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), $precision) . $suffixes[floor($base)];
}

echo formatBytes(57044287, 0); // 58MB

echo formatBytes(5700044287, 0); // 5GB -Show in 5000MB
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: What your problem? Please clarify what you want and currently what happen?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function formatBytes($size, $precision = 2){
    $mb = $size / 1048576;
    return round($mb, $precision) . 'MB';
}

echo formatBytes(57044287, 0); // not 58MB - 54 MB!
print "\n";
echo formatBytes(5700044287, 0); // 5GB -Show in 5000MB
```

output:

```
54MB
5436MB
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get sizes rounded by their relative size; i.e. 5436 => 5000, 123 => 100.

```
function formatBytes($size, $precision = 2)
{
    $mbs = $size / 1024 / 1024;

    $order = pow(10, floor(log($mbs, 10)));

    return (round($mbs / $order, $precision) * $order) . 'MB';
}

echo formatBytes(57044287, 0); // 54MB
echo formatBytes(5700044287, 0); // 5000MB
```